# Kendo Mobile listview not showing data

Tags: kendo-mobile

Why don't I see anything in my view?

**console.log(d); outputs this ...**

```
[{"id":1,"name":"a","age":1,"photo":"","group":"A"},
{"id":5,"name":"alan","age":22,"photo":"","group":"A"},
{"id":3,"name":"b","age":2,"photo":"","group":"B"},
{"id":2,"name":"c","age":3,"photo":"","group":"C"},
{"id":4,"name":"graham","age":43,"photo":"","group":"G"}]
```

**Code: show**

```
console.log(d);
$("#customers-group").kendoMobileListView({
    dataSource: kendo.data.DataSource.create({data: d, group: "group"}),
    template: "${name}",
    fixedHeaders: true
});
```

**View**

```
<div data-role="view" id="customers" data-title="My Data" data-layout="layout-customers" data-show="show">
     <ul id="customers-group"></ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are working with kendo latest version. because kendo latest version will support grouping, fixed header concept..

Your code is working well.

```
click
```

[here for working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/2TkGR/)